# Limit as $x\to \infty$ of $x^{t-1}e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to evaluate the Gamma function by parts:

$$\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty  x^{t-1} e^{-x}\,dx.$$
Letting $ u= x^{t-1} $ and $ v=-e^{-x}, $
I get $$ \Gamma(t)=-e^{-x}\ x^{t-1}\Bigr|_0^\infty + (t-1)\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\ x^{t-2} dx.$$
The problem is evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty} -e^{-x}\ x^{t-1}.$ If I've done it correctly, we get an indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty.$ What have I done wrong/what assumptions have I missed that allow us to guarantee that $-e^{-x}\ x^{t-1}\Bigr|_0^\infty$ evaluates to $0$?

Comment: $e^x$ grows much faster towards $\infty$ than $x^t$ for any $t$. You can prove this by writing $x^{t-1}e^{-x} = e^{ x \left[\frac{(t-1)\log(x)}{x} -1\right]}$ and taking the limit of this expression (first compute $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x}$). To guarantee that the $-e^{-x}x^{t-1}|_0^\infty$ evaluates to $0$ you also need to ensure that $x^{t-1} \to 0$ as $x\to 0$. This gives a constraint on $t$.

Comment: @Winther How would you evaluate that limit to obtain a determinate form? 
$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{log(x)}{x}$ evaluates to zero but we still have a factor of x in the exponentiation. Thanks

Comment: I'm simply using that since $\log(x)/x\to 0$ we have $(p-1)\log(x)/x -1 \to -1$ so for large $x$ we have $x[(p-1)\log(x)/x -1] \sim -x$. Anyway this is just one possible way, see robjohn answer for (imo) better ways to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without L'Hôpital**

A basic inequality is
$$
1+u\le e^u
$$
From this we get
$$
ue^{-u}\le1
$$
Substitute $u=x/t$:
$$
\frac xt\,e^{-x/t}\le1
$$
Assuming $x,t\gt0$, raise to the $t$ power:
$$
\left(\frac xt\right)^te^{-x}\le1
$$
Therefore,
$$
x^{t-1}e^{-x}\le\frac{t^t}x
$$
Now take the limit as $x\to\infty$

---

**With L'Hôpital**
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{t-1}e^{-x}
&=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x{e^{\frac x{t-1}}}\right)^{t-1}\\
&=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac 1{\frac1{t-1}e^{\frac x{t-1}}}\right)^{t-1}\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Great answer. I would like to ask, however--how would one justify the substitution $ x \mapsto x/t $? Thanks

Comment: We could write it as $ut=x$ so that $\frac xt\,e^{-x/t}=ue^{-u}\le1$.

Comment: How did you obtain $ue^{-u} \le1$ from the inequality? It's late, not seeing it for some reason. Thanks

Comment: Since $1+u\le e^u$, we have $ue^{-u}\le(1+u)e^{-u}\le1$

Comment: Would we have to make a restriction $x^{t-1}e^{-x} \ge0$ to ensure that $0\le x^{t-1}e^{-x}\le \frac{t^{t}}{x}$ and thus, applying logic similar to the squeeze theorem, the limit is guaranteed to be zero and not any negative number?
I'm not sure if this logic is correct.

Comment: @JasonG: The integral is over $x\gt0$, the limit is as $x\to\infty$, and the integral does not converge if $t\le0$. So, yes. $x,t\gt0$.

Comment: Why would the integral not converge if $t\le0$? Sorry last question haha

Comment: @JasonG.: $$\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x \ge\int_0^1 x^{t-1}e^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: I've seen convergence for x>0 for this integral somewhere else on this site. But I'm still confused as to how you produced that bound and how it implies a restriction on t. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonG.: $$\begin{align} \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x &\ge\int_0^1 x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &\ge\int_0^1 x^{t-1}e^{-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\end{align}$$ The first inequality is because we are integrating a positive function over a smaller interval. The second inequality is because $e^{-x}\ge e^{-1}$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @JasonG.: When $t\le0$, $$\begin{align} \int_0^1 x^{t-1}\,\mathrm{d}x &=\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_a^1x^{t-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\left\{\begin{array}{} \lim\limits_{a\to0^+}1-\log(a)&\text{if $t=0$}\\ \lim\limits_{a\to0^+}\frac{1-a^t}t&\text{if $t<0$} \end{array}\right. \end{align} $$ both of which are infinite.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much.